# cmake error ' Could NOT find CXX11 ' VS 2010?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2010

Well I have searched, I know VS2010 is a bit dated however that's what I have right now.

So I assume VS2010 isn't C++11 compliant as I assume that what this error in cmake is complaining about, here is the error. I am trying to build a small game engine.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find CXX11 (missing: CXX11_FLAGS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindCXX11.cmake:60 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)
```

Comment: I don't see a question but I guess you want to compile that, so just use another compiler that supports C++11, be it gcc, visual studio 2013 express, clang or whatever else there is

Comment: When VS2010 was released, not even the name C++11 was known. VS2010 only knows C++0x. So some features of the C++11 standard are supported (lambdas for example), others are not (e.g. threads). Anyhow: I would GUESS, that CXX11 is a custom define in the makefiles. As it states, that flags are missing, you might be able to set them when calling the makefile. If it wouldn't be possible, to compile it with VS2010, the developers would probably check for the general compiler during the make, not just for features. Search the .mk files and look for the define, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the FindCXX11 module. This is a normal(ish)/regular error message from a find module. The 'c++11 compatibility' is a red herring.

Post the FindCXX11.cmake file or just don't use it on Windows/MSVC.

Comment: Yeh I found that, I just commented out this in the main cmakelist,                                                                                                               #find_package(CXX11 REQUIRED)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CXX11_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")